# How do I filter the values of 2 different columns (series) in the same line of code in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I am new to Python and I have the following codes running my Jupyter Notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb
%matplotlib inline

fields = ['Leisure', 'Spa', 'Market', 'Meal Plan Code']
myfile = pd.read_csv('extras/ExtrasSpending.csv', sep=',', encoding =  'latin-1', skipinitialspace = True, usecols = fields)
```

Here is the output from running `myfile.head()`

```
   Meal Plan Code   Leisure     Spa     Market
0   AI              0.000000    0.0     United Kingdom
1   AI              0.000000    0.0     DB Local
2   AI              0.000000    0.0     United Kingdom
3   HB            984.615385    0.0     Other Markets
4   AI              0.000000    0.0     United Kingdom
```

My next line of code reads as follows:

```
mySelectedData = myfile.loc[myfile['Market'].isin(['United Kingdom','Germany'])]
```

This works ok when I run `mySelectedData.head()` to check the results. Now, I need to add another filter on another column to the data; I want to filter the 'Meal Plan Code' only to 'AI'.

I tried this (but it does not work although Python does not throw me an error message):

```
mySelectedData = myfile.loc[myfile['Market'].isin(['United Kingdom','Germany'])],myfile.loc[myfile['Meal Plan Code'].isin(['AI'])]
```

How do I construct the 'mySelectedData' object so that it takes both conditions into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
mySelectedData = myfile.loc[(myfile['Market'].isin(['United Kingdom','Germany']))&(myfile['Meal Plan Code'].isin(['AI']))]
```

Comment: Great! Thanks, it does!